# Excel pivot table make row headers as fields not the column headers

Tags: excel, pivot-table

See the following table. When I select the range and then insert Pivot table, Excel by default makes the months (June-11, Jul-11, etc.) as fields not the row headers (Cost, Revenue, Tax and Profit). Is there any way I can directly make them the fields rather than manually transpose the table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this. if yes then drag values to row headers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd like cost, revenue, tax and profit to be the fields not the months.